# How can I add popup menu in Project explorer context menu, only for .java files in project

Tags: java, plugins, eclipse-plugin, plugin.xml

How can I add popup menu in Project explorer context menu, only for .java files in project. Trying to make some plugin for some tests but I don't know how to get this menu to appear only for .java type of file. I did it for txt file using org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile.

**plugin.xml**

```
  <extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus">
  <objectContribution
        id="org.plugin.generate_test.contribution1"
        objectClass="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResources">
     <menu
           id="org.plugin.generate_test.menu1"
           label="Menu 1"
           path="additions">
        <separator
              name="group1">
        </separator>
     </menu>
     <action
           class="org.plugin.generate_test.popup.actions.GenerateTest"
           enablesFor="1"
           id="org.plugin.generate_test.action1"
           label="Action 1"
           menubarPath="org.plugin.generate_test.menu1/group1">
     </action>
  </objectContribution>
  </extension>
```

[Extensions tab in plug-in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izdIp.png)

Edit:

Now I see that org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus was deprecated, so now can someone tell me how can I make this using menu contribution.
My code:

```
      </menuContribution>
  <menuContribution
        allPopups="true"
        locationURI="menu:org.eclipse.ui.navigator.ProjectExplorer?after=additions">
     <menu
           id="org.plugin.generate_test.menus.popupTestMenu2"
           label="Generate Test"
           mnemonic="P2">
        <command
              commandId="org.plugin.generate_test.command.generateCommand"
              id="org.plugin.generate_test.menus.generateCommand"
              mnemonic="PC2"
              style="push">
        </command>
     </menu>
  </menuContribution>
  </extension>
```

I need to add this command in right click context menu in Project Explorer/Package Explorer only for .java files.

Answer (score 2):

For Package Explorer:

```
locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.jdt.ui.PackageExplorer?after=additions"
```

or for adding to all kind of popups:

```
locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.ui.popup.any?after=additions">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `nameFilter` attribute of `objectContribution`.

```xml
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus">
   <objectContribution
        adaptable="true"
        objectClass="org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile"
        nameFilter="*.java"
        id="org.plugin.generate_test.contribution1">
```